# Ambiguous overloading with operator[] and operator int()

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I am creating a class Item, and each Item is a key/value pair. Also, each Item may also contain subitems:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


class Item
{
    private:
        std::string key;
        unsigned int value;
        std::vector<Item> subitems;


    public:
        Item( const std::string& key = "", const int& value = 0 )
        : key( key ), value( value ){ };


    public:
        // Search or Create new SubItem.
        Item& operator[]( const std::string& key )
        {
            for( auto& subitem : subitems )
                if( subitem.key == key )
                    return subitem;

            subitems.push_back( Item( key ));
            return subitems.back( );
        }


    public:
        // Assign new value to Item.
        Item& operator=( const int& value )
        {
            this->value = value;
            return *this;
        }


    public:
        // Get value from Item.
        operator unsigned int( ) const
        {
            return value;
        }
};



int main( void )
{
    Item item;


    item["sub"] = 42;
    unsigned int sub = item["sub"];


    std::cout << std::to_string( sub ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get:

*error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘Item’ and ‘const char [4]’)*

If I create a member method *unsigned int Get()* instead of *operator int()* it does compile. But I wanted the class to work the same way that std::map works:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>



int main( void )
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> item;


    item["sub"] = 42;
    unsigned int sub = item["sub"];


    std::cout << std::to_string( sub ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get it working?
Thanks!

Comment: Item& operator[](const char* key) - decide your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are conflicting with the builtin `operator[](unsigned int, const char *)` (yes, that's a thing).

Implicitely converting the operand to a `std::string` or implicitely converting the `Item` to an `unsigned int` before applying the `operator[]` is equivalent for the compiler, so it can't choose between the two.

You can work around this by adding an explicit `const char*` overload to your class' `operator[]` that defers to your `std::string` implementation.

```
// Search or Create new SubItem.
Item& operator[]( const char* key ) {
    return (*this)[std::string(key)];
}
```